# loginview shows "welcome system-name/administrator" and logout for the first time page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I modified my code to use LoginView and before I had a button in one of my aspx page to redirect to login.aspx and another button for logout and it was all working fine and now I have a LoginView in my master page instead of the button and I have added the code below.But when I load the page it shows my status as loggedin before I even login to the page and I have another page login.aspx to actually enter the credentials and username ,password are stored in sql server.
Here is the code for loginView

```
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/home.aspx"/> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
```

Is it behaving like this because I havent used roles and membership ?Please help me.I have no luck searching for the problem in internet

Answer (score 1):

Try FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, persistCookie). and then redirect to inner pages.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.Functions are working fine..I got the hint and I checked my web.config file.It had the authentication mode set to windows.Now I changed it to forms.everything working fine.Thank you once again